# How to update an input cell in excel

Tags: excel

Ok.. I have tried to solve this problem all day and now I am asking for help

**What I Have:** In excel, I input a value of 101 in cell A1. Next to it, in cell B1, I have a drop down list that shows the units of A1. Now it is Pa. So I have (101 | Pa)

**What I want**: I change B1 drop down list to atm, and I want it to automatically update the value in cell A1 to 1 | atm.

I have a workaround that requires another cell for the user to input, and then update according to B1 but this is not so clean and professional.

I hope you can understand my question.

You input is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the input cell of the number to be formatted with the number and the unit? So B1 is the selection of a unit, but in A1 you show the number plus a pipe plus the unit? So your expectation I would presume would be that after formatting A1 to 101 | Pa and the user selecting A1 to update the number to 102 you would not want the  "| Pa" part in there while editing. In short I am trying to understand what you are aiming for.

Comment: What ever the unit is when a number is inputted to A1 will be the true value. Then, changing B1 will update A1 accordingly. For example, if someone does not want to use inches but cm, they would input a value 1 in A1 with B1 set to in. Then, when you change B1 to cm, it would update to 2.54 | cm.

Comment: I think that using VBA is a little over-zealous for this. Probably all you need is a good formula and possibly a reference table. I think I know what you're getting at, but I need more info. Converting from inches to centimeters is straightforward enough, but the 101 to PA and 1 to ATM has me confused. Can you provide the full list of what's in your dropdown and the corresponding values that should be returned?

Comment: Its not the details of the unit conversion but the method of doing it that I would like to know (so ignore the PA, atm example) .. I will try what chirs has suggested..

Comment: Using your inches to cm example. If A1 had 2.54 as a value, how would you know that wasn't inches that was entered? Or are you wanting 2.54|cm to appear in A1 combined? and B1 will only show cm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some VBA for this.

Using a Change event to detect when the units are changed, update original values

Put this in the Workbook module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim OldUnit As Variant
    Dim NewUnit As Variant
    Dim ConversionFactor As Double
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 2 Then
        ' Save new units
        NewUnit = Target
        ' prevent recalling this code when we update cells
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ' Get old units
        Application.Undo
        OldUnit = Target
        ' put new units back on sheet
        Target = NewUnit
        ' work out your conversion factor based on old and new units
        ConversionFactor = 0.5 ' for testing
        ' update value
        Target.Offset(0, -1) = Target.Offset(0, -1) * ConversionFactor

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Neilsen, You are awsome!